# Degree of extension fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

I've been working my way through some problems to get this idea solidified but now I've run into something odd. How do I find the degree of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{1+ \sqrt{2}})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$? Would it be degree 4 because we have the polynomial $X^{4}-2X^{2}-1 = (X^{2}-1)^{2}-2$?

Comment: It would be degree _at most_ four because of that. There's still the formality of showing that there is no smaller-degree polynomial over the rationals with $\sqrt{1 + \sqrt2}$ as root.

Comment: Of course, Loopy, the degree of minimal polynomial giving the degree of extension.

Answer (score 1):

You can observe that this biquadratic polynomial has two real roots and two complex conjugate roots, so it splits, over the reals, as
$$
(X-\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}})(X+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}})(X^2+aX+b)
$$
where $a^2-4b<0$. By uniqueness of decomposition over the reals, the polynomial is not reducible over the rationals: just consider the possible factors.

You can use the irrationality of $r=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}$, which follows from $\sqrt{2}=r^2-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Or, you can also argue that
$$
\Bbb Q\subset\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2})\subset\Bbb Q(\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}})
$$
and each intermediate extension has degree $2$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Here's a hint to show your polynomial is irreducible (ie. And therefore a minimum polynomial):

Let $X = Y+1$, then use Eisenstein's Criterion.